Plotting brms random effects with tidybayes
Tidybayes can make great-looking plots for the output of Bayesian models, but it's not clear (as far as I can see) how to do this for different types of models.
So for fixed effects, we can do this (generate model first & look at the variables):
modd1 <- brm(hp ~ mpg + cyl + am + (1 + gear|mpg), data = mtcars)
get_variables(modd1)

modd1 %>%
  gather_draws(b_mpg, b_cyl, b_am) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = .variable, x = .value)) +
  stat_halfeyeh()

A model that only has a random intercept is described in the vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidybayes/vignettes/tidy-brms.html#intervals-with-densities) --- with the cars data set, smth like this:
modd2 <- brm(hp ~ (1|gear), data = mtcars)
get_variables(modd2)

modd2 %>%
  spread_draws(b_Intercept, r_gear[gear,]) %>%
  mutate(condition_mean = b_Intercept + r_gear) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = gear, x = condition_mean)) +
  stat_halfeye()  


But what about the random effects in modd1? Since there is a fixed effect of mpg and random int. & slopes for mpg for each gear, the main intercept (b_Intercept) and b coefficient (b_mpg) have to incorporated somehow, as the inclusion of (1 + gear|mpg) generates offsets from the the main intercept and b coefficient. But how?

The model hp ~ mpg + cyl + am + (1 + gear|mpg) doesn't really make sense. First, mpg is a continuous variable, not a grouping factor. In fact, the goal is to predict mpg (miles per gallon) based on the other columns which describe the model of the vehicle. Second, it also doesn't make sense to use the same variable as both "fixed" and "random".

Some Cross Validated threads that may be helpful: What is the difference between fixed effect, random effect in mixed effect models?, Mixed Model Analyses with Interactions in the Random Effects Structure, Can random slopes also be included as fixed effects?, How to deal with competition for variance between a fixed and random effect?

@dipetkov these are good responses but my one quibble is that there may indeed be a reason to have the same variable in the fixed and random parts of the formula. For example mpg ~ hp + (1 + hp | group) would model a global slope for the effect of hp on mpg and a random slope for each group. The random slope would tell us how much the slope within each group deviates from the global slope.

@qdread Yes, I know about random slopes. There's a difference between (A|B) and (B|A). What doesn't make sense is a specification like A + (B | A) or even simpler A + (1 | A). In the latter model there is a fixed effect for each observed level a of A and also a random intercept for as. It's this that doesn't make sense.

@dipetkov completely agree. I was just trying to avoid a potential misunderstanding for people reading this.
